# Do we need to request Gmail Schema whitelist request for each environment?

Tags: google-schemas

We are trying to integrate with Google Schema for my Transactional Emails. When I look at the Registration part I understand it correctly, if my website sends 5 emails like Welcome, Forgotpassword, order purchased, Shipped, Delivered. We need to whitelist separately for each email. 
The question I have now is, how about if we want to enable it for both test environment as well as production? Where my test VS production "from" email address domains are different. Do we need to submit separate requests for an email per environment?
One more point my test environment is a ldap protected so outsider won't have access to it. If google team wants to validate something against my test website to navigate on different pages for whitelist that is not possible

Thanks
Samba Damerla